# Gmail app doesn't sync email at all when on Mobile Data

Tags: sync, notifications, gmail, samsung-galaxy-s-3

I have a Samsung Galaxy S3 and I love the new Gmail app. Works awesome. My only problem is that it doesn't sync emails (I don't receive any new notifications when new emails arrive, I have to manually click refresh in the app which is annoying) when I'm on Mobile Data. When I'm on Wifi I receive notifications almost instantly. I've searched on Google Help but couldn't find anything.

I guess I could use the Email app but I don't like that as much as the Gmail app.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Please, don't sign your posts, your signature is already on the bottom of the post

Comment: Also, are you running any custom ROM or it's stock?

Comment: It's possible that your phone is set to restrict data while on Mobile Data -- Android 4.0 and newer have this feature.  Poke around in the settings and see if that's the case.

Comment: I've upgraded to Jelly bean and I have the same problem. Found that setting in Settings > Mobile Data > Gmail > "Restrict background data" but it's disabled so that's not it...

Comment: I did a factory reset and that didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Who is your carrier? Maybe they are blocking Gmail/Google. Why they'd do that I don't know.

Comment: Hi, my carrier is Orange. Turns out that nothing syncs while on Mobile Data but manual refresh and browsing the net works. That's weird.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found out the problem. Orange Wap was selected instead of Orange Internet in Settings > Access Point Names.

Answer (score 3):

Just found this thread and it helped me solve the same issue (gmail not syncing on mobile data) on my Galaxy S3. Under settings/data usage/gmail I found that 'restrict background data' was ON. Just for gmail, not globally. Not sure when or how that got checked, but it may have been that way out of the box since my gmail has **never** synced on mobile data, even with a factory wipe.

Anyways, hope that helps someone else out there.

Answer (score 2):

Ensure that on the device `Settings | Data usage | Mobile | Mobile data` is set to **ON** and that if `Set mobile data limit` is checked that you haven't reached that limit.

Comment: It's on and there's no limit. I've updated to Jellybean and I have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that the Sync option is enabled for gmail?

Go to `Settings`->`Accounts`->`Google`->`Your account` -> `Gmail` this last must be checked.

Also check if the Sync option is active at all.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, my Gmail & everything from google on Accounts and sync is checked. It works fine when on Wifi, just not on mobile data.

Comment: Try to clean the app data. Go to `Manage Apps`->`Search for Gmail app`->`Clear Data` and `Clear Cache`

Comment: done and still doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this sync was my problem too...just tried below settings and worked:

1. Go to Settings
2. then to Data usage
3. click Menu button
4. check Auto Sync

Now go to your Account section where you should see all account syncs are enabled :)

Answer (score 1):

It might be caused by a proxy server configured in the APN. See this question: [Google apps losing connection to the servers when on mobile data](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/33354/google-apps-losing-connection-to-the-servers-when-on-mobile-data).

Answer (score 1):

my problem was that "google play services" was restricted over cellular network so my emails only synced when i had wifi. Under settings/data usage/google play services...turn data restriction off. This solved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

What was my problem:
My emails were syncing over wi-fi connection but NOT via Mobile Data.
Application I used for emails are in-built Mail and Gmail apps.

How I solved it:

1. Tried playing with all different settings but that did not help.
2. Later Identified that the problem was with Setting of sync.
3. Go to Settings > Sync. Enable ONLY the first option i.e. "Sync"
   Make sure that you DO NOT select the second option i.e. "Wi-Fi only"

Now, your emails should start syncing over both - wi-fi and Mobile Data too.

Even after this if you have a problem, then:
1. Made sure that the Data restriction is OFF for your specific app or is OFF in general.
2. Your Data is switched ON and has correct APN configured.
3. Your Background Data usage is set to enable for the specific apps.

Answer (score 0):

If none of the other things work, go to `Apps > Google services framework`. Click `Clear cache and data` button. Then, reboot.

Answer (score 0):

My Phone Galaxy S4:

On mobile network only my Gmail app was not pushing automatically, gmaps was slow, youtube was not working or really slow and Calendar wasn't syncing.

After looking on the internet I was not able to find the solution. I have tried everything that was simple like clear cache, reboot, sync OFF/ON ...

But finally with this site I come up with the APN reset solution. I did it and also I have found that google services had the check mark ON for restrict background data. Setting/data usage/google services

I have never touched this option before so I don't know why it was checked. After these two steps my phone works perfectly now.

Answer (score 0):

I went through every item under data usage to check for restrictions.  For me it was Exchange Services that was restricted. Solved. Thanks.

Comment: Solved how? What does "restricted" mean? I guess you're talking about "background data" here?

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem in samsung galaxy J5 running lollipop ( 5.1.1) . I had to enable following under the Settings/Data Usage/Background data
1) Email
2) Gmail
3) Google Settings

I had initially only enabled 1 & 2. Yahoo email was working but Gmail was not. Once i enabled Google Settings , the Gmail sync also started working.

Comment: I only want to thank you because you solve my problem. Thanks so much.
I have also Samsung J5. Maybe I can help I go to settings. data usage. background data and checked google settings. I don't know when or how it was unchecked. After that I can sync "Sync Push subscription" and now works.